# Not Getting speed in Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac

Tags: wifi, wpa2, hostapd

I got **50MB/s speed** in Station mode but using AP mode I got only **8MB/s to 10MB/s**

**How to increase my Transfer speed**

> Details:
>   WiFi Card = Atheros QCA6174 **802.11ac**
>   OS = Ubunut 16
>   Hostapd = 2.6

```
$ iw reg get

country CH: DFS-ETSI
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS
    (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

My *hostapd.conf*

```
### hostapd configuration file
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211

### IEEE 802.11
ssid=UMAX
hw_mode=a
channel=36
max_num_sta=10
auth_algs=1

### DFS
country_code=IN
ieee80211d=1
#ieee80211h=1

### IEEE 802.11n
ieee80211n=1
ht_capab=[HT40+][LDPC][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40][TX-STBC][RX-STBC1][DSSS_CCK-40]

### IEEE 802.11ac
ieee80211ac=1
vht_oper_chwidth=1
vht_capab=[MAX-MPDU-11454][RXLDPC][SHORT-GI-80][TX-STBC-2BY1][RX-STBC-1]
vht_oper_centr_freq_seg0_idx=42

### IEEE 802.11i
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_passphrase=0123456789
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

### hostapd event logger
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=2
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2

### WMM
wmm_enabled=1
uapsd_advertisement_enabled=1
wmm_ac_bk_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_bk_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_bk_aifs=7
wmm_ac_bk_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_bk_acm=0
wmm_ac_be_aifs=3
wmm_ac_be_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_be_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_be_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_be_acm=0
wmm_ac_vi_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vi_cwmin=3
wmm_ac_vi_cwmax=4
wmm_ac_vi_txop_limit=94
wmm_ac_vi_acm=0
wmm_ac_vo_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmin=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmax=3
wmm_ac_vo_txop_limit=47
wmm_ac_vo_acm=0

### TX queue parameters
tx_queue_data3_aifs=7
tx_queue_data3_cwmin=15
tx_queue_data3_cwmax=1023
tx_queue_data3_burst=0
tx_queue_data2_aifs=3
tx_queue_data2_cwmin=15
tx_queue_data2_cwmax=63
tx_queue_data2_burst=0
tx_queue_data1_aifs=1
tx_queue_data1_cwmin=7
tx_queue_data1_cwmax=15
tx_queue_data1_burst=3.0
tx_queue_data0_aifs=1
tx_queue_data0_cwmin=3
tx_queue_data0_cwmax=7
tx_queue_data0_burst=1.5
```

**iwconfig output**

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

**iw list output :**

```
Capabilities: 0x19ef
        RX LDPC
        HT20/HT40
        SM Power Save disabled
        RX HT20 SGI
        RX HT40 SGI
        TX STBC
        RX STBC 1-stream
        Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
        DSSS/CCK HT40
    Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
    Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
    HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
    VHT Capabilities (0x339071b2):
        Max MPDU length: 11454
        Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
        RX LDPC
        short GI (80 MHz)
        TX STBC
        SU Beamformee
        MU Beamformee
        RX antenna pattern consistency
        TX antenna pattern consistency
    VHT RX MCS set:
        1 streams: MCS 0-9
        2 streams: MCS 0-9
        3 streams: not supported
        4 streams: not supported
        5 streams: not supported
        6 streams: not supported
        7 streams: not supported
        8 streams: not supported
    VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
    VHT TX MCS set:
        1 streams: MCS 0-9
        2 streams: MCS 0-9
        3 streams: not supported
        4 streams: not supported
        5 streams: not supported
        6 streams: not supported
        7 streams: not supported
        8 streams: not supported
    VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
```

Answer (score 0):

By "Station Mode" do you mean IBSS (ad-hoc device to device)?

The speed of an 802.11 wireless link varies on many factors. Given that two STA (client or access point) support the same capabilities, the important items are background noise (noise floor) and received signal strength (RSSI). The greater the difference (SNR) the higher the transmission speed. Distance between transmitter and receiver greatly affects received signal strength (twice the distance, four times weaker signal).

When you were testing IBSS, your two devices were probably very close together. Compare the signal strength of your two devices to the signal strength of your access point.

Overhead on an 802.11 network using access points is around 20% to 30% of available bandwidth. Factor in that a client must transmit to the access point, then the access point must transmit to the other client and you will see that getting 33% of the advertise speed is doing well.

Increase the distance between the clients and the access point, have obstacles such as walls, other interfering devices (cordless phones, microwave ovens, Bluetooth, USB 3 hubs, etc.) will reduce your real-world performance.